# Error code in let-in expression

Tags: sml

I have this SML code. I don't know why I cannot compile this :

```
fun score = 
    let
       val sum = 3; (* error at this line : SYNTAX ERROR : inserting LPAREN *)
       if sum div 2 > 0
       then sum = 0
       else sum = 1
       (*some other code*)
    in
       sum (* I want to return sum after some steps of calculation *)
    end
```

Comment: Perhaps you wan't to elaborate on what you wan't to do with the code. It makes absolutely no sense, as it is now.

Comment: It seems to me that beyond mere syntax issues, he is actually trying to _assign_ to `sum` in the conditional. But of course, there is no such thing as assignment to a value, identifiers are not mutable in SML (or other functional languages).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are more issues with your code, than jacobm points out.
You are also missing a function argument. Functions in SML always takes one argument. For example

```
fun score () = 
    let val sum = 3
        val sum = if sum div 2 > 0
                  then sum = 0
                  else sum = 1
    in
       sum
    end
```

However this still doesn't make much sense. since the expressions `sum = 0` and `sum = 1` evaluates to a Boolean.

A let-expression is used to make some local declarations which are only visible inside the `in ... end` part. Thus the calculations you wan't to do with sum, should probably be done inside the `in ... end` part, unless you wan't to express it as a means of a function.

One such example is

```
fun score () = 
    let val sum = 3
    in
      if sum div 2 > 0
      then ...
      else ...
    end
```

If we look at the syntax of a let-expression, it probably makes more sense

```
let
  <declaration>
in
  <expr> ; ... ; <expr>
end
```

Since if-then-else is an expression, it can't be in the "declarations part" by itself.

Comment: Good point --- I fixed the first error and didn't really read the rest of the code :)

Answer (score 2):

That syntax just isn't legal -- in between `let` and `in` all you're allowed to have is a series of `val name = expr` fragments. You can do this, though:

```
fun score = 
    let val sum = 3
        val sum = if sum div 2 > 0
                  then sum = 0
                  else sum = 1
    in
       sum
    end
```

I would consider it a bit of a weird style to use `sum` for both variable names, but it's legal.